# Outdated React Native Project

Tags: react-native, npm, mobile, deprecated, projects-and-solutions

I posted this question yesterday, but apparently worded it badly, so I'm trying again.

I'm working on a project that had been closed for a couple of years and reopened. During that time, a large number of the included node_modules have gone out of support (or at least the versions being used), React Native has been updated several times, new rules came out for building iOS projects, etc. leaving the project in a pretty broken state.

The previous team that worked on the project didn't leave much in the way of documentation, and we're stuck figuring out the details on our own.

There are two of us on the UI development, and we're able to build the project as-is using all of the old components. However, as soon as we start upgrading anything, we run into conflicts.

I've spent a good bit of time (several different times combined) trying to find a way to get the upgrade started, but everything I've tried runs into conflicts.

For purposes of clarity, he problems that I encounter include:

npm reports ERESOLVE Unable to resolve dependency tree
many errors (hundreds) come out of the XCode build - version compatibility, not allowed to use deprecated components, legacy build system outdated, conflicting pointer assignments, etc
All tools need to be upgraded (Node, npm, Android Studio, Xcode, React, React Native, Gradle, etc
Is there somewhere I can find an article or tutorial or something with a step-by-step, repeatable process for creating a project from scratch and adding the required components in an orderly way so that I can upgrade the whole process at once?

Also, I know that a lot of open source projects support their products with paid services, but that doesn't appear to be the case with React Native as far as I can tell. Is there somewhere we can find a project / build expert to come in and work with us on this?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your previous question got closed, not because it was worded poorly, but because it will lead to opinion-based answers. The same is likely to happen with this. Stack Overflow is well-suited to questions where there are concrete answers.

Comment: Have a try with upgrading the version of react native and used libs. and fresh pod install